# HTML5 canvas - rotate object without moving coordinates

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

What I have is this:
[image: Tank]

What I want is to rotate the **red** rectangle e.g. 20 degrees, but this is what I end up with:
[image: Bad rotation]

As you can see, the rectangle is rotated perfectly, but it's moved and doesn't match the black object anymore.

My code is:

```
context.save();
context.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180); // in the screenshot I used angle = 20
context.translate(angle * 4, 2);
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fillRect(x + 14, y - 16, 5, 16);
context.restore();
```

I want to make the rectangle turn without moving from its position.

Thanks.

Comment: [Apple Developer Library on canvas and rotating around the center.](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/Translation,Rotation,andScaling/Translation,Rotation,andScaling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010542-CH8-SW11) A good resource with example code.

Answer (score 73):

**Sounds like you want to rotate the rect around its centerpoint.**

Red rectangle is original,  Yellow rectangle is rotated around the centerpoint.

[image]

To do that you need to first `context.translate` to the rect's centerpoint before rotating.

```
// move the rotation point to the center of the rect

    ctx.translate( x+width/2, y+height/2 );

// rotate the rect

    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
```

Note that the context is now in its rotated state.

That means drawing position [0,0] is visually at [ x+width/2, y+height/2 ].

So you must draw the rotated rect at [ -width/2, -height/2 ]  (not at the original unrotated x/y).

```
// draw the rect on the transformed context
// Note: after transforming [0,0] is visually [-width/2, -height/2]
//       so the rect needs to be offset accordingly when drawn

    ctx.rect( -width/2, -height/2, width,height);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/z4p3n/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var startX=50;
    var startY=80;

    // draw an unrotated reference rect
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(startX,startY,100,20);
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
    ctx.fill();

    // draw a rotated rect
    drawRotatedRect(startX,startY,100,20,45);

    function drawRotatedRect(x,y,width,height,degrees){

        // first save the untranslated/unrotated context
        ctx.save();

        ctx.beginPath();
        // move the rotation point to the center of the rect
        ctx.translate( x+width/2, y+height/2 );
        // rotate the rect
        ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);

        // draw the rect on the transformed context
        // Note: after transforming [0,0] is visually [x,y]
        //       so the rect needs to be offset accordingly when drawn
        ctx.rect( -width/2, -height/2, width,height);

        ctx.fillStyle="gold";
        ctx.fill();

        // restore the context to its untranslated/unrotated state
        ctx.restore();

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not exactly: http://puu.sh/3gnZT.png I need it not to be at the centerpoint because it's a "Tanks" game (where you shoot the other tank) and this is the "gun" you use to aim, so it must stay fixed to the tank (black object)

Comment: @user2479365 markE provided a great and detailed answer woth a nicely commented code. Just adapt `translate()` to your needs. You probably want `-height` instead of `-height/2` or something like that.

Comment: You will probably want to offset your translation using the radius from the center of your tank. You may also find that using a transformation matrix may be more suitable to your needs.

Comment: As  Vedran Šego and GoldfishSandwich said well above, you just have to adjust the rotation point to your desired pivot point --  translate(x,y+height/2) and  rotate(0,-height/2,width,height).

Comment: @markE this is the answer to my own programming question. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a simple function to do this as an alternative to translate and rotate:

This function will let you draw a line starting at x and y, and end at length at angle:

```
function lineToAngle(ctx, x1, y1, length, angle) {

    angle *= Math.PI / 180;

    var x2 = x1 + length * Math.cos(angle),
        y2 = y1 + length * Math.sin(angle);

    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);

    return {x: x2, y: y2};
}
```

Usage:

```
lineToAngle(ctx, x, y, length, angle);
```

## Demo

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    x = 100, y =50, length = 40, angle = 0, dlt = -2;

(function animate() {
    
    //clear
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    lineToAngle(ctx, x, y, length, angle);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.stroke();

    angle += dlt;
    if (angle < -90 || angle > 0) dlt = -dlt;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
})();

function lineToAngle(ctx, x1, y1, length, angle) {

    angle *= Math.PI / 180;
    
    var x2 = x1 + length * Math.cos(angle),
        y2 = y1 + length * Math.sin(angle);
    
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);

    return {x: x2, y: y2};
}
```

```css
body {background-color:#555557}
canvas {background:#ddd;border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of a rectangle, you can just draw a line.

In HTML5 canvas, lines are drawn exactly like rectangles, as such, you can use this function:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

function drawRotatedRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, angle) {
  angle *= Math.PI / 180
  ctx.lineWidth = height / 2
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(x, y)
  ctx.lineTo(x + width * Math.cos(angle), y + width * Math.sin(angle))
  ctx.stroke()
}


drawRotatedRect(ctx, 30, 30, 200, 100, 20)
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rotated Rectangle</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```