# how to rotate a rect and it still move in the right direction based on its rotation

Tags: javascript, html, rotation

I'm making a game in HTML5/JavaScript, and I want the player to rotate, and move in the right direction based on its rotation. here is a link to I got the basic rotation: [HTML5 canvas - rotate object without moving coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125632/html5-canvas-rotate-object-without-moving-coordinates). here is some of my code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var keys = [];

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);

var player = {
x: 10,
y: 10,
width: 15,
height: 15,
color: 'blue',
speed: 3,
rotate: 0,
rotateSpeed: 2
};

function game(){
update();
render();
}

function update(){
if(keys[87] || keys[38]) player.y -= player.speed;
if(keys[83] || keys[40]) player.y += player.speed;
if(keys[65] || keys[37]) player.rotate += player.rotateSpeed;
if(keys[68] || keys[39]) player.rotate -= player.rotateSpeed;
}

function render(){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(player.x+player.width/2, player.y+player.height/2);
ctx.rotate(player.rotate*Math.PI/180);
renderObject(-player.width/2, -player.height/2, player.width, player.height, player.color);
ctx.restore();
}

function renderObject(x,y,width,height,color){
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
}

setInterval(function(){
game();
}, 25);
</script>
```

the player just moves up and down the screen, but I want it to move in the direction its facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to factor the player's angle in when you adjust the speed.  Try something like:

```
function update() {
    if(keys[87] || keys[38]) {
        player.y -= Math.cos(player.rotate*Math.PI/180) * player.speed;
        player.x -= Math.sin(player.rotate*Math.PI/180) * player.speed;
    }
    if(keys[83] || keys[40]) {
        player.y += Math.cos(player.rotate*Math.PI/180) * player.speed;
        player.x += Math.sin(player.rotate*Math.PI/180) * player.speed;
    }

    if(keys[65] || keys[37]) player.rotate += player.rotateSpeed;
    if(keys[68] || keys[39]) player.rotate -= player.rotateSpeed;
}
```

The cos() and sin() are trig functions and take an angle in radians as their argument. Hence the conversion factor of Math.PI/180.

Hopefully, that does the trick. I'm on a tablet and can't test easily from here...

Comment: thanks it works, all but one thing. when I'm rotated 180, or -180, I go the wrong way.

Comment: No worries...  Have fun!