# Rotating lines of ctx in JS canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

If I have the following basic drawing of a triangle in JavaScript canvas, how would I rotate it, say 30 degrees, along the center? This is a bit different then the possible duplicate because it isn't a `rect`, it is a bunch of lines along an origin.

```
// Rotate 30 degrees when origin is (5,5)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(5,0);
ctx.lineTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(0,10);
ctx.lineTo(5,0);
ctx.stroke();
```

So, instead of seeing a normal triangle, you would see a triangle a bit tilted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 canvas - rotate object without moving coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125632/html5-canvas-rotate-object-without-moving-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish that using the **[`rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate)** method of canvas

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var deg = 30;

ctx.save(); // save canvas

ctx.rotate(deg * Math.PI / 180); // rotate canvas

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(5,0);
ctx.lineTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(0,10);
ctx.lineTo(5,0);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.restore(); // restore canvas
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="218" height="218" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3"></canvas>
```

***note:*** *make sure to save the canvas state before rotating and restore it after drawing the triangle, so that the future drawings don't get rotated.*

Comment: You are going to have to add ctx.translate(5,5) and then this would work

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi this does work anyway and if you wanna change the position then you would need *translate*

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to define your triangle in its own local coordinate system. As is you need to follow its origin around the canvas if you plan to move it. But you don`t need to change the triangle just its position and rotation.

So define the triangle as a set of points in its own coordinates system where 0,0 is the center of rotation.

```
// you had
/*
ctx.moveTo(5,0);
ctx.lineTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(0,10);
ctx.lineTo(5,0); */

// subtracting 5 from x and y to give
var triangle = [0,-5,5,5,-5,5];  // dont need the last point will use closePath
```

A function to draw a shape from a set of points makes life a little easier

```
function drawShape(shape, close){
    var i = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(shape[i++], shape[i++]);
    while(i < shape.length){
        ctx.lineTo(shape[i++], shape[i++]);
    }
    if(close){ ctx.closePath() }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Now a function to set the transformation

```
function setPosScaleRotation(x,y,scale,rot){
     ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,x,y);
     ctx.rotate(rot);
}
// and a function to restore the default transform
function restoreDefaultTransform(){
     ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

Now it is easy to draw the shape where you want

```
setPosScaleRotation(5,5,1,deg * Math.PI / 180); // 30Pi / 180 = 3Pi/18 = Pi/6 
drawShape(triangle,true);
```

Or put the transform and draw into the same function

```
function drawShape(shape, close, x, y, scale, rot){
    var i = 0;
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
    ctx.rotate(rot);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(shape[i++], shape[i++]);
    while(i < shape.length){
        ctx.lineTo(shape[i++], shape[i++]);
    }
    if(close){ ctx.closePath() }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Then

```
drawShape(triangle, true, 5, 5, 1, Math.PI /6); 
drawShape(triangle, true, 100, 100,1, Math.PI + Math.PI / 6); // draw at 100,100 at 180 from other triangle
```