# can not rotate a rectangular shape in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new in HTML5 canvas. I am trying to build game area using HTML canvas where  someone can drive around a car inside
Canvas area like if I press the left arrow key the car will turn to the left and if press the right arrow key the car will turn to the right side. And up and down arrow keys are responsible for moving the car upward or downward. And the car must stay within the canvas area.  Here, I use rotate method to turn the car right or left. But it is not working, actually the car is getting away from the canvas and behaving like a crap.
Anyone has any idea to solve the problem? I am totally stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Initially I am displaying a rectangle instead of car.

My js file is given below.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = innerWidth - 100;
canvas.height = innerHeight - 100;
const canvasW = canvas.width;
const canvasH = canvas.height;

let upPressed = false,
  downPressed = false,
  rightPressed = false,
  leftPressed = false;

class PlayerCar {
  constructor(carX, carY, carWidth, carHeight) {
    this.carX = carX;
    this.carY = carY;
    this.carWidth = carWidth;
    this.carHeight = carHeight;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.carX, this.carY, this.carWidth, this.carHeight);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

const playerCar = new PlayerCar(100, 100, 40, 60);
playerCar.draw();

function navigation() {
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      upPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      downPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      rightPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      leftPressed = true;
    }
  };

  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      upPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      downPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      rightPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      leftPressed = false;
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);
  if (upPressed) {
    playerCar.carY -= 5;
  }
  if (downPressed) {
    playerCar.carY += 5;
  }
  if (leftPressed) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(
      playerCar.carX + playerCar.width / 2,
      playerCar.carY + playerCar.height / 2
    );
    ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * 0.2);
    playerCar.carX -= 5;
    ctx.restore();
  }
  if (rightPressed) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(
      playerCar.carX + playerCar.width / 2,
      playerCar.carY + playerCar.height / 2
    );
    ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * -0.2);
    playerCar.carX += 5;
    ctx.restore();
  }

  if (playerCar.carX < 0) playerCar.carX = 0;
  if (playerCar.carX > canvasW - playerCar.carWidth)
    playerCar.carX = canvasW - playerCar.carWidth;
  if (playerCar.carY < 0) playerCar.carY = 0;
  if (playerCar.carY > canvasH - playerCar.carHeight)
    playerCar.carY = canvasH - playerCar.carHeight;

  playerCar.draw();
}

function startGame() {
  animate();
}

startGame();
navigation();
```

Comment: You need a normalized direction vector for the car. When left or right is pressed, you rotate this vector using a 2D rotation matrix (then normalize it again). When up is pressed, you add this vector to the car's position. When down is pressed, you subtract it.

Comment: I think this can help you [html5-canvas-rotate-object-without-moving-coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125632/html5-canvas-rotate-object-without-moving-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first move all of the update info to a method in the car class vice doing it in the animate loop.

This is where `cos` and `sin` come in and getting familiar with angles. You also must understand the canvas relation the the object it draws is always at (x, y) of (0, 0) unless you translate it to the center. To do that draw your object in this manner:

```
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(this.carX, this.carY)
    ctx.rotate(this.angle)
    ctx.rect(-this.carWidth/2, -this.carHeight/2, this.carWidth, this.carHeight);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
```

Use of `save()` and `restore()` are a must unless you want to translate and rotate you object back to its original. It's the same ting but simpler. So now I am translating the car around the canvas and the car itself is drawn at  negative half the width and height to ensure the canvas (0, 0) corner is in the center of the car. This is because canvas always rotates from the top-left corner.

Now create a method called `update()` and put you control logic in there:

```
  update() {
    if (rightPressed) {
      this.angle += this.rot
    } else if (leftPressed) {
      this.angle -= this.rot
    }
    if (upPressed) {
      this.carX += Math.cos(this.angle+toRadians(-90)) * 5;
      this.carY += Math.sin(this.angle+toRadians(-90)) * 5;
    }
  }
```

Be aware I added angle and rot to the constructor also. What this is doing is when you press left or right the car rotate accordingly. As for pressing up we are going to translate it by the rotation. Since this would normally make the car drive to the right we have to also add -90 degrees to the current angle to ensure the car drives forwards. Just remove `+toRadians(-90)` and see what happens.

Multiplying it by 5 is an arbitrary number for speed. You can even make it part of the constructor and set it there. i.e. `this.speed = 5`

Doing the same thing for `downPressed` but instead use `+toRadians(90)`

`toRadians()` is just a simple function added to your code to convert degrees to radians.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;
const canvasW = canvas.width;
const canvasH = canvas.height;

let upPressed = false,
  downPressed = false,
  rightPressed = false,
  leftPressed = false;

class PlayerCar {
  constructor(carX, carY, carWidth, carHeight) {
    this.carX = carX;
    this.carY = carY;
    this.carWidth = carWidth;
    this.carHeight = carHeight;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.rot = 0.1; //control how fast it turns
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(this.carX, this.carY)
    ctx.rotate(this.angle)
    ctx.rect(-this.carWidth/2, -this.carHeight/2, this.carWidth, this.carHeight);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  }
  update() {
    if (rightPressed) {
      this.angle += this.rot
    } else if (leftPressed) {
      this.angle -= this.rot
    }
    if (upPressed) {
      this.carX += Math.cos(this.angle+toRadians(-90)) * 5;
      this.carY += Math.sin(this.angle+toRadians(-90)) * 5;
    }
    if (downPressed) {
      this.carX += Math.cos(this.angle+toRadians(90)) * 5;
      this.carY += Math.sin(this.angle+toRadians(90)) * 5;
    }
  }
}

function toRadians(deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI) / 180;
}

const playerCar = new PlayerCar(100, 100, 40, 60);
playerCar.draw();

function navigation() {
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      upPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      downPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      rightPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      leftPressed = true;
    }
  };

  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      upPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      downPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      rightPressed = false;
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      leftPressed = false;
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);
 
  if (playerCar.carX < 0) playerCar.carX = 0;
  if (playerCar.carX > canvasW - playerCar.carWidth)
    playerCar.carX = canvasW - playerCar.carWidth;
  if (playerCar.carY < 0) playerCar.carY = 0;
  if (playerCar.carY > canvasH - playerCar.carHeight)
    playerCar.carY = canvasH - playerCar.carHeight;

  playerCar.draw();
  playerCar.update();
}

function startGame() {
  animate();
}

startGame();
navigation();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

To be clear on why your code is not doing what you expect think about this. You are trying to translate and rotate the context without ever accessing the object. If you were to add `ctx.fillRect()` to your animate loop would you think it's going to just know that you want to change the car? Same goes for translate and rotate. Try adding a `fillStyle` and `fillRect` to your rightPressed

```
if (rightPressed) {
    ctx.save();
    playerCar.carX += 5;
    ctx.translate(
      playerCar.carX + playerCar.width / 2,
      playerCar.carY + playerCar.height / 2
    );
    ctx.rotate(45);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'grey'
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.restore();
  }
```

You will see when you press `right` the context does what you want just not the context of the object. This is why adding it directly top the class should be done. Now you are specifically targeting the object you want.